# Extract values from list of dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

I have the following list of dictionaries from which I would like to the values of each dictionary separately.

```
stocks=[{'BEST':'GOOG.O','BEST':'FB.O'},
              {'REST':'SAN.MC','REST':'CDCUF.PK','REST':'EDN.BA'}]
```

the desired output would be:

```
list1=['FB.O','GOOG.O']
list2= ['SAN.MC','CDCUF.PK','EDN.BA']
```

I thought it was going to ok to do the following:

```
dict1=stocks[0]
best_sto=list(dict1.values())

dict2=stocks[1]
rest_sto_rest=list(dict2.values())
```

However from dict1 the output is `['FB.O']` and from dict2 returns `['EDN.BA']`

Comment: Also worth mentioning that `dict.values()` already returns a `list`. There's no need to pass it into `list()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dictionaries you provide all have the same key for all values. Only one of the values will be kept, and it is the last one.

For dicts, every key must be unique. They are not multi-maps to support multiple identical keys.

Comment: The interesting part is OP went on to part 2 of the project when part 1 was totally broken.